# Synchronizing Hard Coded values between Prod and Dev

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, token

I am in a situation where I am reading from a proprietary database that I have no way of altering for my needs. The brilliant architects have a horribly normalized database and when they setup the server in Dev, they didnt think to match the primary keys (integer identity values) between Dev and Prod.

In this situation we have had to write the queries where we are using hardcoded values - example `where productid = 12345`. `12345` is not always the same product in Dev as Production. This means maintaining 2 sets of sql code. And their is a high risk for potential errors (not deploying correct scripts). I prefer the standard of testing in Dev and deploying the exact same code to Production. This minimizes risk.

Note: I am simplifiying this for purposes of this example but the way it was architected and the way we need to do the query requires the hard coding. (sorry for my blashpemy).

Somebody said that you can do this with SQL Server Token Replacement but I cant seem to find too much on it, online. Apparently you can set the values you need (productid's) in a sql file and it will deploy it to the server replacing your `tokens` with the correct hard coded values.

I am just looking for some guidance in getting started with this.

Comment: simply create a table with the the fields and values you need in your database.   Insert respective environmental ids into this table.  Write your queries pulling the values from this table.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this with a parameter table:

```
Parameter   Value
ProductId   12345
```

And a function to get the parameter:

```
WHERE productid = (SELECT Parameter('ProductId'))
```

Comment: thank you... interesting, I will have to look into that

Comment: This is probably the best solution for the least investment.  I was faced with something similar, but they were guid keys and not identities... so I bit the bullet and actually wrote a script that would do all the updates necessary to make the keys the same across databases. It was a big one-time expense that eliminated the problem going forward. But it's not always feasible to do that. And this was a very special case where it was.